# How to delay time while making an applet in java for a search code

Tags: java

I'm making a java applet which demonstrates linear search and I want the elements of the array to change colour after every 2 seconds. how do i delay time in this case

Comment: Do you have some piece of code to show?

Comment: it si too long to fit in here

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for this purpose. Specifically:

```
  int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //...Perform a task...
      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

However, Applets are not the best (probably not even a great) way to build a web application. [Here are some of the common complaints](https://www.java.net//pub/pq/89). Have you considered building an HTML 5.0 web application instead?

Comment: thank you :) no i havent because its for a school project and i have to use applets but thankks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call Thread.sleep (2000) somewere in loop that implements you search algorithm.

Comment: dont you require a throws exception for that